# How to get users by specified tag?

Tags: postgresql

I have 3 tables users, tags, user_tags. I try to fetch users with theirs tags with next query:

```
SELECT
        u.*,
        t.id    AS tag_id,
        t.value AS tag_value
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM users
      WHERE type = 1
      LIMIT 10
      OFFSET 0
     ) u LEFT OUTER JOIN (user_tags ut INNER JOIN tags t ON t.id = ut.tag_id)
                ON u.id = ut.user_id;
```

But I want to add condition to fetch users only if they have the specified tag. I tried to do it with next:

```
SELECT
        u.*,
        t.id    AS tag_id,
        t.value AS tag_value
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM users
      WHERE type = 1
      LIMIT 10
      OFFSET 0
     ) u LEFT OUTER JOIN (user_tags ut INNER JOIN tags t ON t.id = ut.tag_id)
                ON u.id = ut.user_id AND ut.tag_id = :tag_id;
```

But in this case I get fetch users without the rest of their tags.
Please advise a good practice to fetch users by specified tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should modify the subquery (that chooses the 10 users), not the main query (that fetches all the tags of the specific users):

```
SELECT
        u.*,
        t.id    AS tag_id,
        t.value AS tag_value
FROM (SELECT ui.*
      FROM users AS ui
      WHERE ui.type = 1
        AND EXISTS
            (SELECT 1 FROM user_tags AS uti 
             WHERE ui.id = uti.user_id
               AND uti.tag_id = :tag_id
            )
      LIMIT 10
      OFFSET 0
     ) AS u 
     -- the rest of the query (un)changed
  LEFT JOIN user_tags AS ut  ON u.id = ut.user_id
  LEFT JOIN tags AS t  ON t.id = ut.tag_id ;
```

Comment: Thank you, I know that solution, I tried to do it without subquery in subquery:)